# Generics: cannot convert from <capture#1-of ? extends Object,D> to <S,D>

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class structure:

```
public interface CopyMapper<S, D> {
    public D map(S sourceObject);
}

public interface CopyMapperFactory {
    public <S, D> CopyMapper<S, D> getMapper(Class<S> sourceClass, Class<D> destinationClass);
}

public class Mapper {
    public <S, D> D map(S source, Class<D> destinationClass) {
        //This is where I get compile time error
        CopyMapper<S, D> copyMapper = mapperFactory.getMapper(source.getClass(), destinationClass);
        return copyMapper.map(source);
    }
```

My Eclipse compilator gives me the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from CopyMapper<capture#1-of ? extends Object,D> to CopyMapper<S,D>
```

As far as I know, all generic types extend `Object`, so I don't see where the problem is?

We are trying to preserve an interface. This is the original method of the interface:

```
<T> T map(Object source, Class<T> destinationClass)
```

I tweaked it a little bit so that the classes that use the interface don't get affected:

```
<S, D> D map(S source, Class<D> destinationClass);
```

Basically, we are mapping Pojo's, we've been using DozerMapper, but now, the major architect wants compile time safety, and the DozerMapper isn't. For example if a pojo's field gets updated (renamed, deleted) we need to manually update the xml, that describes the mapping between the pojo's (the xml is used in case of nontrivial mapping, for example, when the names of fields of the pojo's don't correspond completely, which is often the case)

Now, we have copy classes, hundreds of them, one for each mapping between pojo's. We are trying to use the Factory Design patter to return a specific mapper class (implementing the `CopyMapper` interface) based on the source class and destination class.

Comment: How did you get `CopyMapperFactory ` to compile?

Comment: It just compiles. Why? Do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread

Comment: Why do you pass Class<S> at all? Can't you just pass S?

Comment: Then I'll have to cast it to a specific type, which is not compile time safe.

Comment: Why? S is your specific type. What do you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: If you update a field name, then yes, you also have to adjust the XML configuration.  Are these all straight-up maps between two POJOs with no customization required?  Do the POJOs have the same field name between the two, even after the rename? Or are you using `CustomConverter` (when you really should use [`DozerConverter`](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/dozer/DozerConverter.java))?

Comment: I may be wrong, but another problem with Dozer is performance, we have thousands of pojo's to map. We've had a look at the implementation and we've seen some triply nested loops when the dozer goes through all pojo fields using reflection, if we have ready copy classes, we don't have that problem.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that.  Dozer is pretty performant for what it does; if you've got claims about speed, you'd want to use a profiler to verify it.  Above that, you haven't quite satisfied my questions posed to you - I understand your motivation to want to have type safety, but in what circumstances are you trying to get it?  What kind of mapping are you doing which you absolutely require it?  Are there `CustomConverter`s lurking around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `getClass` method returns `Class<?>` and not `Class<S>`, as I think you are expecting. See [`Object#getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) in the API.

As it returns `Class<?>` you lose type information, so you really have this:

```
CopyMapper<?, D> copyMapper = mapperFactory.getMapper(source.getClass(), destinationClass);
```

You know source class is `S` so I think you can safely add a cast, but you will get a warning:

```
CopyMapper<S, D> copyMapper = mapperFactory.getMapper((Class<S>)source.getClass(), destinationClass);
```

Comment: So that is a safe cast, because I'm sure that the class of `source` is `S`, right?

Comment: If this were strictly a generics problem, I'd think you're right.  But what I'm suspecting here is that there's a deeper issue going on with their usage of Dozer.